# Android: IntentService start itself

Tags: android, android-intent, intentservice

Can a class that extends IntentService call startService() to start itself again?

```
public class testService extends IntentService{

public testService (String name){
   super(name);
}

onHandleIntent(Intent intent){

   startService(testService.class); //CAN YOU DO THIS?
}
```

Comment: I would bet on a stackoverflow error

Comment: Couldn't you just have that code inside of a class, and then in the main class do  `onHandleIntent(Intent intent){

   startService(testService.class);}`?

Comment: I am just wondering if a Service can start itself again. Its is similar to calling onStartCommand explicitly. Obviously you do not want to call onCreate explicitly for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is yes. I use same pattern for longpoll operation.
There will not be any stack overflows because is is not a recursion from system's point of view.
Although it is better to use AlarmManager to restart service after some time to conserve power.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is "Yes".

Starting a service all depends on the type of Context you have (http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/)

And the only Difference between an IntentService and a regular Service is that it automatically kills itself when its done and it also spawns a background Thread so that you can do a long operation (Like Network).